# Send Gravity Forms to 3rd Party API and check for duplicates at API before sending

Tags: wordpress, api, gravityforms

Ok I'm hoping that this is pretty straightforward. But I doubt it.

I currently have a Gravity Forms form which is sending to an external API successfully. Using the PUT method. This is fine. But now my client wants to add some extra functionality to check for duplicates within the API before it will submit. Essentially making sure that the user hasn't already registered. I'm using this method within my functions.php but this only sends to the third party it doesn't do any checking of duplicates:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 ); 
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {

$post_url = '#URL#';
$body = array(
    'name' => rgar( $entry, '1' ),
    'email' => rgar( $entry, '2' ),
    'password' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
    );
GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: body => ' . print_r( $body, true 
) );

$request = new WP_Http();
$response = $request->post( $post_url, array( 'body' => $body ) );
GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform_after_submission: response => ' . print_r( 
$response, true ) );
}
```

I need to be able to get the form to check if the email address is used on the system and if so then to not send the form, and to display an error.

Please help.... i'm really stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Using post_to_third_party you are able only to send it where third party can compare values.

If I understood well what you need is:

-get email field from the form,

-get list of registered emails,

-compare it,

-submit or don't submit the form.

Take a look at https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_submission/

I would start from this point:

```
//MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password.";
$dbname = "wordpress";
//Create connection
$wpdb2 = new wpdb($username,$password,$dbname,$servername);
```

To get email of user who is submmiting the form:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_email =  $user->email;
```

OR you are able to get the user email from form field inside of the hook that you will use

```
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission', 'pre_submission_handler' );
function pre_submission_handler( $form ) {
 $user_email = $entry["1"];
}
```

To get emails of registered users you can use

```
$wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '.$user_email , ARRAY_A);
```

I hope this hints will make you hit the road again.
If you need more help - I will try my best.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Adam :) sort of.. I need it to check the list of email addresses at the API so the process would be this:

1. User fills in details.
2. User presses button to send details.
3. The API then checks that email address isn't already in use on the system (which is an external API, not a user on the WordPress system).
4. If user is not there adds user, it if is there shows error saying that the email address has been used (or words to that effect).

I hope that helps explain a bit further.

Comment: I am pretty sure that in this case you also need to use pre_submission hook - If you will use after_submission it might be to late, because data was send. After my work I will get back here and try to give you more support if will be need.
But in my opinion you need to send the email to third party and then maby you can get Api response like in example n1 here:https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_submission/

Comment: Thats very kind Adam. I've looked at the gform_pre_submission and I'm sure you're right. The issue is going to be that I can't necessarily get the Database login details to be able to check this. The Put function that I was using to send the data is pretty much all I have. Would it need to have this information to be able to check what users are in the Database. If so I may have to pass it back to the client to finish off.

Comment: It is complicated for me, I have no idea how to solve problem of few people submitting form at the same time. API endpoint could serve true or false based on email that you send or maby API could send AJAX post with true/false and some kind of form submission id/timestamp. I hope that will help you a little bit.

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution where a user gets registered on wordpress and the 3rd party api when filling out the form but on neither if the api response sends an error such as username or email already in use and tell them to modify. I thought perhaps this https://github.com/zaus/forms-3rdparty-inject-results could help if it could process that check/response first then include searched for response errors as a hidden field, which conditionally halts the rest (wordpress user registration addon) processing and generates an error/please modify message first?